# Should stdlib classes with emplace-mechanisms be friendable?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std, private-methods, emplace

*I am wondering if this an stdlib bug, an oversight, my own error or intended by the standards committee.*

If a type `T`'s constructor (any of its constructors) is non-public, an unrelated container cannot emplace an element using that constructor, clearly. However, my reasoning was that if I befriend said container, various emplace's should be allowed, but due to the way the standard library containers are generally implemented over myriad of sub- and helper-classes this doesn't seem to work.

Consider this:

```
#include <optional>

class T { 
  friend std::optional<T>;
  T(int) {}
};  

int main() {
  std::optional<T> opt;
  opt.emplace(7);
}
```

If this is compiled with g++ 10.2, it complains that no suitable function `std::optional<T>::emplace(int)` exists. Notably it does *not* complain that `T::T(int)` is private within this context as I would have expected.

-> **[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3qhb5r)**

Note that this would work with a self defined class:

```
class H {
  void f() {
    T(7); // fine iff H is a friend of T (otherwise "private within this context" error)
  }
};
```

So, to restate my question from above, *should* this work?

Comment: These classes typically have requirements that client type must satisfy. These requirements typically never include any special rules for being friends with someone. e.g. "class should be default constructible", not "class should be default constructible when constructor is invoked from that particular place of standard library". Rewriting requirements in such a specific manner would certainly complicate code, e.g force  `std::is_default_constructible` to be reimplemented dozens of times.

Comment: @user7860670 Yes, in the case of `std::optional<T>::emplace` cppreference states: *This overload only participates in overload resolution if `std::is_constructible<T, std::initializer_list<U>&, Args&&...>::value` is true.* But does so **ONLY** for the `initializer_list` version. For the other one, no such requirement is expressed (at least over at cppreference).

Comment: And yes, I agree that this would likely complicate code for the reason you mention.

Comment: cppreference states *that T must be constructible from Args... for overload (1)*

Comment: @user7860670 Well, it doesn't state for whom, if you want to be nitpicky.

Comment: *Requires: is_constructible_v<T, Args&&...> is true.* - from standard

Answer (score 0):

> However, my reasoning was that if I befriend said container, various emplace's should be allowed

That might result in certain code duplications or code that needs to be move to a place where it probably should not be.

e.g. `std::queue` itself is just a wrapper, that forwards the member function class to the used container (which is `std::deque<T>` by default), so either `std::queue` needs to construct that object or you also need to make `std::deque<T>` fried, same problem is with move and copy constructors.

Another case could be `std::list` which might forward the construction to the `node` type.

And if you make an exception for one type like `std::optional` then this won't be consistent throughout the std lib.